# Multiple Stopwatch Timers in ListView

Tags: android, listview, stopwatch

I have a ListView in my android app that should contain stopwatch timers along with start and pause buttons in each of its row. The problem is, when I start the timer in one row, and If I start another one belonging to another row in the ListView, the second one also starts from the same time at which the first one is at. So basically they're not independent. How can I modify my code, so that each row has an independent timer and its time should get effected only when it's (start or stop) button is pressed.

Here's my custom adapater class

```
public class CustomAdapterStopWatch extends BaseAdapter {

private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
Context context;
public static List<String> timerList;
private long startTime = 0L;
private Handler customHandler;
long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;

public CustomAdapterStopWatch(Context context, List<String> timerList) {

    this.context = context;
    this.timerList = timerList;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    customHandler = new Handler();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return timerList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return timerList.get(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.stop_watch_list_view, null);
        holder = new CustomAdapterStopWatch.ViewHolder();
        holder.timerTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timerInListView);
        holder.startTimer = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.startTimerInListView);
        holder.pauseTimer = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.stopTimerInListView);
        holder.timerTextView.setTag(position);
        holder.startTimer.setTag(position);
        holder.pauseTimer.setTag(position);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        // Alarm alarm = (Alarm) getItem(position);
    } else {

        holder = (CustomAdapterStopWatch.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.timerTextView.setText(timerList.get(position));

    holder.startTimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            customHandler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
                    updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
                    int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
                    int mins = secs / 60;
                    secs = secs % 60;
                    int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
                    holder.timerTextView.setText("" + mins + ":"
                            + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                            + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
                    customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
                }
            }, 0);

        }
    });


    holder.pauseTimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
            customHandler.removeCallbacks(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
                    updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
                    int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
                    int mins = secs / 60;
                    secs = secs % 60;
                    int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
                    holder.timerTextView.setText("" + mins + ":"
                            + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                            + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
                    customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

The layout file that I am using is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerInListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="00:00:00"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGray"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/stopTimerInListView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="Pause"
        android:background="@color/colorGreen"/>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/startTimerInListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
    android:text="Start"
    android:background="@color/colorGreen"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/stopTimerInListView"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/stopTimerInListView"
    android:layout_marginEnd="22dp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

The stopwatch class in which I use the adapter is as following:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stop_watch);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewInStopWatch);
    timerList = new ArrayList<String>();


    timerList.add("00:00:000");
    timerList.add("00:00:000");
    timerList.add("00:00:000");
    timerList.add("00:00:000");

    customAdapter = new CustomAdapterStopWatch(StopWatch.this, timerList);
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
 }
```

***UPDATE***

I changed the code as following:

```
public class CustomAdapterStopWatch extends BaseAdapter {

private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
Context context;
public static List<TimerState> timerList;
private long startTime = 0L;
private Handler customHandler;
long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;
HashMap<ViewHolder,Integer> mHashHolder;
TimerState state;

public CustomAdapterStopWatch(Context context, final List<TimerState> timerList) {

    this.context = context;
    this.timerList = timerList;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    customHandler = new Handler();
    mHashHolder = new HashMap<ViewHolder,Integer>();
    state = new TimerState();

    // assuming you need to update the timer after every second.
    customHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (ViewHolder holder: mHashHolder.keySet()) {
                state = timerList.get(mHashHolder.get(holder));

                // update the state
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}

 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.stop_watch_list_view, null);
        holder = new CustomAdapterStopWatch.ViewHolder();
        holder.timerTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timerInListView);
        holder.startTimer = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.startTimerInListView);
        holder.pauseTimer = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.stopTimerInListView);
        holder.timerTextView.setTag(position);
        holder.startTimer.setTag(position);
        holder.pauseTimer.setTag(position);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        mHashHolder.put(holder,position);

        // Alarm alarm = (Alarm) getItem(position);
    } else {
        // holder is being used again, so need to update its new position
        // following line should be synchronized if timer is updated
        // in a separate thread
        mHashHolder.put(holder, position);
        holder = (CustomAdapterStopWatch.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.timerTextView.setText(timerList.get(position).currentTime);

    holder.startTimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            if (state.isPaused) {
                state.timeSinceStarted = String.valueOf(SystemClock.uptimeMillis());
                state.isPaused = false;
            } else {
                // nothing
            }

        }
    });


    holder.pauseTimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (state.isPaused) {
                state.isPaused = true;
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}


public void startTime(final TextView t) {
     Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            t.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
    };
}
```

However after I press the buttons, nothing happens. Have I missed something?

**UPDATE 2**

```
 public CustomAdapterStopWatch(Context context, final List<TimerState> timerList) {

    this.context = context;
    this.timerList = timerList;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    customHandler = new Handler();
    mHashHolder = new HashMap<ViewHolder,Integer>();
    state = new TimerState();

    // assuming you need to update the timer after every second.
    customHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            for (ViewHolder holder: mHashHolder.keySet()) {
                state = timerList.get(mHashHolder.get(holder));

                long tmp;
                if (!state.isPaused) {
                    tmp = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    state.currentTime += tmp - state.timeSinceStarted;
                    state.timeSinceStarted = tmp;
                }
                updatedTime = state.currentTime;
                int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
                int mins = secs / 60;
                secs = secs % 60;
                int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
                // set the text of the view in holder
                holder.timerTextView.setText("" + mins + ":"
                        + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                        + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));

                // update the state
            }
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
public class CustomAdapterStopWatch extends BaseAdapter {

private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
Context context;
public static List<TimerState> timerList;
private long startTime = 0L;
private Handler customHandler;
long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
long updatedTime = 0L;
HashMap<ViewHolder,Integer> mHashHolder;
TimerState state;

public CustomAdapterStopWatch(final Context context, final List<TimerState> timerList) {

    this.context = context;
    this.timerList = timerList;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    customHandler = new Handler();
    mHashHolder = new HashMap<ViewHolder,Integer>();
    state = new TimerState();

    // assuming you need to update the timer after every second.

    customHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (ViewHolder holder: mHashHolder.keySet()) {
                state = timerList.get(mHashHolder.get(holder));

                long tmp = 0;
                if (!state.isPaused) {
                    tmp = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    state.currentTime += tmp - state.timeSinceStarted;
                    state.timeSinceStarted = tmp;
                }
                updatedTime = state.currentTime;
                int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
                int mins = secs / 60;
                secs = secs % 60;
                int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
                // set the text of the view in holder
                holder.timerTextView.setText("" + mins + ":"
                        + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                        + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
              //  notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(context,"I got here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // update the state
            }
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return timerList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return timerList.get(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.stop_watch_list_view, null);
        holder = new CustomAdapterStopWatch.ViewHolder();
        holder.timerTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timerInListView);
        holder.startTimer = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.startTimerInListView);
        holder.pauseTimer = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.stopTimerInListView);
        holder.timerTextView.setTag(position);
        holder.startTimer.setTag(position);
        holder.pauseTimer.setTag(position);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        mHashHolder.put(holder,position);

        // Alarm alarm = (Alarm) getItem(position);
    } else {
        // holder is being used again, so need to update its new position
        // following line should be synchronized if timer is updated
        // in a separate thread
        mHashHolder.put(holder, position);
        holder = (CustomAdapterStopWatch.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.timerTextView.setText(String.valueOf(timerList.get(position)));

    holder.startTimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            if (state.isPaused) {
                state.timeSinceStarted = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                state.isPaused = false;



            } else {
                // nothing
            }

        }
    });

    holder.pauseTimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (!state.isPaused) {
                state.isPaused = true;
            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}


public void startTime(final TextView t) {
     Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            t.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }
    };
}
private class ViewHolder {

    TextView timerTextView;
    Button startTimer;
    Button pauseTimer;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are 2 things you are doing wrong.

1. You are using same variable updateTime for each of your timer. Instead you should maintain a state for each of your timer. So its better to have a separate class for that. For e.g.

   ```
   class TimerState {
        boolean isPaused = true;
        long currentTime = 0;
        String timeSinceStarted;    // matters only when the timer is started
     }
   ```

So pass the array list of above class to your adapter. So that timerList will be arrayList of TimerState.

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stop_watch);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewInStopWatch);
    timerList = new ArrayList<TimerState>();


    timerList.add(new TimerState());
    timerList.add(new TimerState());
    timerList.add(new TimerState());
    timerList.add(new TimerState());

    customAdapter = new CustomAdapterStopWatch(StopWatch.this, timerList);
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

 }
```

2. This one is a bit tricky. What adapter does is it reuses the view and you are updating the timer of some view item (using postDelayed), even when its not visible to the user. So instead you should only be updating the timer of those views which are visible to the user. I am creating a hashmap which will keep the holder of all views which are visible to the user and we will have a runnable which will update only those views.

Your adapter will be

```
    public class CustomAdapterStopWatch extends BaseAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    Context context;
    public static List timerList;
    private long startTime = 0L;
    private Handler customHandler;
    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    long updatedTime = 0L;
    // this will contain the holder of all visible views
    HashMap mHashHolder;

    public CustomAdapterStopWatch(Context context, List timerList) {

        this.context = context;
        this.timerList = timerList;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        customHandler = new Handler();

        // assuming you need to update the timer after every second.
        customHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TimerState state;

                    for (ViewHolderItem holder: mHashHolder.keySet()) {
                        state = timerList.get(mHashHolder.get(holder));
                        long tmp;
                        if (!state.isPaused) {
                           tmp = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                           state.currentTime += tmp - state.timeSinceStarted)
                           state.timeSinceStarted = tmp;
                        }
                        updatedTime = state.currentTime

                        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
                        int mins = secs / 60;
                        secs = secs % 60;
                        int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
                        // set the text of the view in holder
                        holder.t.setText("" + mins + ":"
                          + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                          + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
                    }
                    customHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                }
         }, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return timerList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return timerList.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.stop_watch_list_view, null);
            holder = new CustomAdapterStopWatch.ViewHolder();
            holder.timerTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timerInListView);
            holder.startTimer = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.startTimerInListView);
            holder.pauseTimer = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.stopTimerInListView);
            holder.timerTextView.setTag(position);
            holder.startTimer.setTag(position);
            holder.pauseTimer.setTag(position);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

            mHashHolder.put(position, holder);

            // Alarm alarm = (Alarm) getItem(position);
        } else {

            // holder is being used again, so need to update its new position
            // following line should be synchronized if timer is updated
            // in a separate thread
            holder = (CustomAdapterStopWatch.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            mHashHolder.put(holder, position)
        }
        holder.timerTextView.setText(timerList.get(position));

        holder.startTimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                if (state.isPaused) {
                    state.timeSinceStarted = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    state.isPaused = false;
                } else {
                   // nothing
                }

                // logic for showing the timer will be in onScroll method
            }
        });


        holder.pauseTimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!state.isPaused) {
                    state.isPaused = True

                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I still however don't get how can I use the timerstate array in the listener of the two buttons and the handler function.

Comment: Logic will be similar to what you coded but for each individual timer. It will go in the OnScroll method.

Comment: that's actually pretty neat. I like this solution a lot. It's better than using a thread in combination with a handler. Should save resources too if I think about it. 
@Mr.Dev so what you would have to do is putting your logic from    `holder.startTimer.setOnClickListener` into the `OnScrol`l method. Change it a bit to make it work with the new logic and it should be working

Comment: @Nico Actually there is still an issue, when user is not scrolling the screen, all visible views will not get updated. So I have done some edits. Your suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: This line of code gives an error of "Incompatible types"..'For ViewHolder and mHashHolder.keySet().                                      customHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TimerState state;
                for (ViewHolder holder: mHashHolder.keySet()) {
                    state = timerList.get(mHashHolder.get(holder));

                    // update the state
                }
            }
        }, 1000);'

Comment: I haven't run the code, but type of mHashHolder will be HashMap<ViewHolder, Integer> where ViewHolder is the name of class you defined as your holder.

Comment: The code is not complete. You have to write the logic in customHandler runnable to update the view.

Comment: @Mr.Dev I have moved the logic in runnable.

Comment: Hey thanks again for answering. However its still not working. Nothing happens when I click the button to start the timer. Please see my Update 2.

Comment: I have not tried to run the above code. There might be some syntax issue, my point was just to give you the basic idea how it should be done. You can use the debugger to find out if the runnable is properly being called or your timer item is getting updated.

Comment: I have been trying to make it run for the past 3 days. But still not getting the right result. If I put the runnable inside the onclick of the button then it gives out the timer value after I press the button, but doesn't continue to display the time continuously. If I keep the runnable where you suggested, it doesn't display the time at all.

Comment: Actually runnable was not getting called periodically, I did 1 line change and I ran the code myself (but with only seconds to show as text), Its working fine. Tell me if you still face any problems.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I added the line. The timer does start now however it works for only a single row timer e.g. if i press start on the timer in the first row, the timer in the third row starts to count. After that no matter which timer I start or stop, the changes get reflected on only that third row timer. No other timer starts or stop. On restarting the activity, if I press start on the last timer, the first one starts to count. And the count has a gap of few milliseconds. Could you please run my code and try? See Update 3.

Comment: There is 1 more change I did, holder should be set before adding it to the hashMap, that's the reason why some other row's counter started.

Comment: Thanks once again. I updated the change in my code and now the timer starts for the row for which the button is pressed. But multiple timers don't work. After starting one timer, the other timers don't work. And there start/stop buttons reflect changes on the timer that was started earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.startTimer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            customHandler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
                    updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
                    int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
                    int mins = secs / 60;
                    secs = secs % 60;
                    int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
                    holder.timerTextView.setText("" + mins + ":"
                            + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                            + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
                    customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
                }
            }, 0);

        }
    });
```

is your problem. So you see that you declared one variable to count and when you start a second one, you count up on the same variable `updatedTime`.
To get it independent you need to change the function to not count on the same variable. My first idea would be creating a new Thread on invoking a start of a timer and cloning the variable. But I didn't programm for android in quite som time.